# Can't push changes to Liberty for Java "Starter Code", HelloResource.java or index.html, back to bluemix

Tags: java, push, ibm-cloud, war

I went to the Dashboard, selected Create App, selected Web, selected Liberty for Java, continue, and named it EasyMeditation.

I went through the steps of "Start coding with Cloud Foundry command line interface".

I Downloaded the Starter Code, extracted it to a library EasyMeditation, switched to the library and executed the supplied cf api and cf login commands.

Then I changed "Hello World" to "Hello There World" in HelloResource.java and changed "...in your dashboard" to "...in MY dashboard in index.html.

Then I issued a cf push EasyMeditation command to compile and change the app.

I then opened http://easymeditation.mybluemix.net and my changes don't appear.

From the date modified field on the .war file it appears that it was not recompiled.

Am I suppose to recompile the app and create the .war file?

Answer (score 2):

To push your application with cf command line interface you have to compile it first using some IDE and export it to .war file. Every change made to nonstatic files (eg. .java) requires compilation to be able to notice those changes.

If you are using Eclipse for you project, type "bluemix" in Eclipse marketplace, and then install "IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix". It's simple tool which makes pushing apps to bluemix much easier. You create connection with bluemix like creating a new web server.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can try using Git and deploy your app through dev op services. Yet another option is to use the Bluemix Live Sync to update the app and develop as you would on your desktop.  See the link below for more details:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/deploy_devops.html

Answer (score 1):

To compile the application, install Apache Ant and run `ant` at the root directory of the source. `ant` will read the build.xml, and generate a .war file.

Then, push the war file `cf push EasyMeditation -p ./webStarterApp.war`